# Is there a way to allow an authenticated user to add to another users post?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type that uses a field collection field and I would like for one user to create the initial node, then have other users able to add field collection entries after it has been submitted. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to give the users permission to content level.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict who can edit a field, and make that groups of users different from the group of users who can edit the node, you can use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

[image: screenshot]

Users who has the permission to edit a field still need the permission to edit the node.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.